# onTimer method, why timer state is null?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a simple application like this (inside keyed process function).

As you can in the code section below, I am always first getting timerObject from state and if it does not exists, I am creating a new one, and update the state. Thus, there will never be a empty/null state.

And basically this state is just for keeping the object last time, for example:

- If an object was seen at time 10:15 then register time will be 10:30.
- However if an object was seen again at time 10:25, then register time will be updated to 10:40
- If process function runs onTimer at time 10:40, that's means there was no object in 15 mins interval, then i am just clearing my state.

**Problem is that logger sometimes prints null for the state object. This should not be the case right?**

```java
public class ProcessRule extends KeyedProcessFunction<Tuple, LogEntity, Result> {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProcessRule.class);

    private transient ValueState<TimerObject> timerState;

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception{
        ValueStateDescriptor<TimerObject> timerValueStateDescriptor = new ValueStateDescriptor<TimerObject>(
                "timerStateForProcessRule",
                TypeInformation.of(TimerObject.class)
        );
        timerState = getRuntimeContext().getState(timerValueStateDescriptor);
    }

    @Override
    public void processElement(LogEntity value, Context ctx, Collector<Result> out) throws Exception{
        registerTimer(value, ctx);
        if (conditionTrue) {
           convert Result add to collector
        }
    }

    private void registerTimer(LogEntity element, Context ctx) throws Exception{
        TimerObject stateTimer = timerState.value();

        if (stateTimer == null){
            stateTimer = new TimerObject();
            long timeInterval = 15 * 60 * 1000;
            stateTimer.setTimeInterval(timeInterval);
        }

        stateTimer.setCurrentTimeInMilliseconds(element.getTimestampMs());
        timerState.update(stateTimer);
    
        ctx.timerService().registerProcessingTimeTimer(stateTimer.getNextTimer());
        // getNextTimer => currentTime + timeInterval
    }

    @Override
    public void onTimer(long timestamp, OnTimerContext ctx, Collector<ValidationResult> out) throws Exception{
        TimerObject stateTimer = timerState.value();
        LOGGER.info("Timer fired at the the timestamps: {} for: {}", timestamp, stateTimer);
        timerState.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is most probably coming from the fact that You are registering multiple different timers, but You don't seem to delete them when registering new ones. So, this basically means that when first-timer fires the `timerState` is cleared, but seconds again next timer may also fire since it might have been registered to fire 3 sec after the first one and in this case the `timerState` may already be `null`.

Comment: You mean, should i call **ctx.timerService().deleteProcessingTimeTimer(long time);** before register new time? If it is, parameter of this deleteTimer should be the exactly the same of the previous registeredTimer or it could be equal or larger than previous registered timer. (I assumed that deleteProcessingTimeTimer(123123) will delete "all timers" before or equals to "123123"?)

Comment: It should be exactly the same as the registered timer, You could keep the timestamp of previously registered timer or see if You can get it from Your `TimerObject`. So, that inside of `registerTimer` function You may remove the previous timer. The other option can be to simply ignore that, but You need to take into account that multiple timers may fire consecutively and state may be actually null. NOTE: Registering too many timers may have effect on performance and checkpoint size, so You should consider that when doing that.